# How can I preserve cell outputs on uploaded notebooks?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I uploaded a previously created Jupyter notebook. I could initially see all the cell outputs in Colab right after uploading it, but if I close the notebook and come back to it later -- or if I share the notebook with a coworker -- then all the cell outputs have been cleared, which is quite annoying.

This is happening even though I've verified that the following two checkboxes are UNCHECKED:

`Edit > Notebook settings > Omit code cell output when saving this notebook`

`Tools > Preferences > New notebooks use private outputs (omit outputs when saving)`

From what I can tell, it looks like the cell outputs get preserved across sessions for notebooks created and edited in Colab, but not for notebooks that were created elsewhere and then uploaded. What am I missing? How can I preserve cell outputs across sessions in uploaded notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open the file from Drive directly in Jupyter?

If so, you'll need to save the full file using the File -> Download ipynb menu item.

By default, Colab saves outputs using a different format to support incremental saves, so the Drive file created during auto-save will show outputs, but only in Colab itself, and you'll need to download the full ipynb to export to other notebook viewing tools.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I'm just trying to view the notebook in Colab in the browser. I can see the code and everything fine, it's just that the cell outputs go away after the initial session in which I uploaded the notebook.

Comment: Does this reproduce in an incognito window? Extensions are a common cause of issues of this type.

Comment: The outputs which are disappearing- are they all outputs for the notebook, or just some outputs? If just some, do they happen to be larger ones? (as in, a graph or image, not just a few lines displayed).

When the outputs go missing, are they missing from within Colab as well, or just missing when viewed in Jupyter?

Comment: Bob, while trying to test your suggestion, I found that I can't seem to reproduce the problem on any new notebook, even trying similar steps on notebooks of similar size, with lots of different variations... so, yeah, I dunno. @blois to answer your question it was every single cell output that disappeared, both in the Colab web viewer and the same after downloading it to a local notebook. But, well, if I can't reproduce the problem, then I guess I don't know where there is to go from here.